# AutocompleteTextView text clear if entered value is not found from list

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I have a dynamic arraylist that contains String values. I want to match one of its values with AutocompleteText whatever the user has typed/entered. In case the value is not matching with any of the Arraylist values I would like to clear Autocomplete Text.

Couple of Ways I have tried.

- Match the typed or user selected value from autocomplete text with list directly without any loop using "contains" method. Didn't achieve the expected result.
- Store the values in String[] array from list and loop through it and match it with user input/selection from Autocompletetext. Didn't achieve the result this way too.

Please provide any ideas on how to clear text from autocompletetextview if value is not found?

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: I tried to answer i think it will work you did not put any code that's why i tried to use an algorithm mostly

Comment: I have put my code below and it worked this way.

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify any language that's why i will answer in kotlin

1. Override onKeyDown method and let's say you will check when enter pressed check if given keycode value equals to `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER`
2. In if block get your text and use an algorithm like below

   `val arr = intArrayOf(1,2,3) if (textFromTextView !in arr)` it means your typed text not in your array and if this condition is true
3. use `autoCompleteTextView.replaceText("")` and i hope it will work for you.I never tried but i searched for you.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I am using Java for development. About the I have done something like below and it worked.  
String str = AutoCompleteText.getText().toString(); //Get this on Click of autocompletetext dropdown item
AutoCompleteText.SetonFocusChangeListener(...){
boolean isFound;
if(!hasFocus){
  for(inti=0;i<list.size;i++){
    if(str.equals(list.get(i).getValue()){
         isFound=true; 
        }
  }
  if(!isFound){
    AutoCompleteText.setText("");
  }
}
}

Comment: Yeah it should work,too.My and your algorithm are similar.